# цепочка словообразовательная

Tags: словообразование

Добрый день! Помогите составить словообразовательную цепочку слова "священник". Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По Тихонову:

***свят***ой -> свят-**и**-ть -> свящ-**енн**-ый -> священн-**ик**

Comment: Спасибо большое)))